# IF statement just responding to the most recent if statement's result

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

I am going to try to explain this the best I can. I have a task to make a pay phone price calculator based on day, duration, and time call started. I did two of the if statements and realized whenever I put in my answers all it does is print the result off the most recent if statement and does not really listen to what I want it to do. It is a bit hard to explain so I will just put my code, my input, and my result.

Code:

```
day = str(input('Enter the day the call started at: '))
start_time = float(input('Enter the time the call started at (hhmm): '))
duration = float(input('Enter the duration of the call (in minutes):'))
cost = duration

    if (start_time >= 08.00 and start_time <= 18.00 and day == "Mon" or "Tue" or "Wed" or "Thr" or "Fri"):
        cost = duration * 0.40
    
    if (start_time < 08.00 and start_time > 18.00 and day == "Mon" or "Tue" or "Wed" or "Thr" or "Fri"):
        cost = duration * 0.25
    
    print('$' + str(cost))
```

My inputs:

```
1: Fri, 2350, 22.  2: Sund, 2350, 22.
```

My results:

```
1: $5.5.  2: $5.5.
```

As you can see it did not even do what is inside the print statement. It just gave me the result of the outcome of the previous if statement. I also tried removing the "and day ==" and what is after and all that did is make the first print statement work fine while the second does not work it just prints my original duration so I think I messed up bad.

Comment: This doesnt do what you think `and day == "Mon" or "Tue" or "Wed"` here you are saying check the truthness of is day equal to monday. Otherwise check the truthness of the string "Tue". All non empty strings are true.  so it will always evaluate true in the first if

Comment: Your second if statement will never be `true`

Comment: So what can I do? I tried removing all the or's already and it still didnt help it just gave me no results.

Comment: @HamzaFarooq So what can I do I already tried removing the ors and I believe I just got no results

Comment: Follow the link to the duplicate to find out what to do.

Comment: `day in ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thr", "Fri]`

Comment: @EmeraldThunder- will try rn thank you

Answer (score 0):

When you're trying to connect multiple conditions using logical operators you have to compare each string separately.
I mean it needs to be like this

```
day == "Mon" or day == "Tue" or day == "Wed"
```

And so on...

Comment: or if you have a lot you can store them in a tuple or list and just check your value is in it. Like `day in ("Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri")`